# incorrect format for an int

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagrid, sql-injection

I have a Form that contains 3 TextBox,a comboBox,and a DatagridView,in which a client tape an int for TextBox1 or a part of a Text in TextBox2 or TextBox3 or for more specification he can choose an item of the comboBox1 the result is displayed in the dataGridView(numeo_cpte,intitulé_cpte).My problem is I get northig of the result in the dataGridview and an erreur of conversion of the int =>the format of entered data is incorrect

this is my code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            int a =Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //format of enetered data is incorrect
            String b = textBox3.Text;
            String c = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            String d = textBox4.Text;

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            req="select numero_cpte,intitulé_cpte from compte where numero_cpte='"+a+"' OR intitulé_cpte like '%"+b+"%' OR type_cpte='"+c+"' OR index_full_text_cpte like'%"+d+"%';";       
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(req,connection); 
            int o = sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(o + " succès");
            dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, connection);
            dr.Fill(ds, "compte");
            compteDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["compte"];
            connection.Close();
```

I add the line

```
        int n=0;
        int a =int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out n)?n:0;
```

and this is what I get,no errors but I didn't get any result displayed in the datagridView:

[image]

I made "success" just for test 
thanks again for your help

Comment: Probably text in the textbox1.Text is not numbers.

Comment: An what exactly is the value of `TextBox1.Text`?

Comment: the error says - you have not enterd integer in `textbox1`.use `int.TryParse()`

Comment: it's a number (an int) :) @Kamil T

Comment: @Lina `FormatException` means that it's not an integer ;) Can you paste the value in here?

Comment: @Lina And what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: In other news: your SQL is **dangerously** broken. You should immediately stop, parameterize that sql, and **review all other data access code in your application(s)**. SQL injection is a **massive** and **trivially exploitable** problem.

Comment: Please indicate a: the exact value of `textBox1.Text`, and b: your local culture (as this impacts formatting, unless an invariant culture is explicitly specified)

Comment: For info: http://pastie.org/9285871

Comment: @Lina are you sure that there isn't any whitespace after your string? Have you tried something like `string x = "10130000"; int y = Convert.ToInt32(x);` ? Did it fail? Have you tried `ToInt64` instead of `ToInt32`?

Comment: @KamilT thanks for your reply it works now with "AND",in which I should fill all fields that's why it didn't work at first

Answer (score 2):

This error will occur if the string is not formatted as an integer.
For example:

```
Convert.ToInt32("1")        // returns 1
Convert.ToInt32("1.1")      // is not in a recognizable format
```

You should try using a regular expression to apply some formatting first or use a try/catch statement. If you are still having trouble, could you set a debug break point at this position and provide us a copy of the offending string provided by textbox1.Text?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Kamil :D it wouldn't let me make the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Add a try catch to handle any errors and log them as well :

```
StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(path,true);
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  try
           { 
            int a = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            ///...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
         }
```

**EDIT :**
As it been pointed pointed by most, it is most probably that your problem lies to the fact that Textbox1 is not feeded with a valid string represantion of integer. However in anycase, this conclusion must come up from an external log and not a crush of your program because it fails to handle the given exception.

Comment: Where is that `Streamwriter` coming from?

Comment: you mean the typo? or that is must include System.IO??

Comment: And how does that help? We already know that it's a `FormatException`, so I'm afraid your code is a bit pointless.

Comment: @KamilT, If the only point to solve OPs direct Q may code is indeed pointless (as Marc's comments are pointless regarding OPs questions). In my opinion the goal is except of helping the OP to solve the exact problem optimise their general code...

Answer (score 1):

Replace `int a =Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);` from the below statements.

```
int n = 0;
int a = int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out n)?n:0;
```

In the above case if `textbox1.Text` is a valid integer then you will get result in `a` else you will get 0.

Answer (score 1):

Are you check your direct query with this parameter given result(s) like

```
--Replace the value with actual value
select numero_cpte,intitulé_cpte from compte where numero_cpte=cast(123 as int) OR intitulé_cpte like '%abc%' OR type_cpte='ddd' OR index_full_text_cpte like'%dasdf%';";
```

Please add cast in your query and remove single quote(') near **a** paramater.

```
req="select numero_cpte,intitulé_cpte from compte where numero_cpte=cast("+a+" as int) OR intitulé_cpte like '%"+b+"%' OR type_cpte='"+c+"' OR index_full_text_cpte like'%"+d+"%';";
```

Comment: it works thanks when I put AND not OR,but What I want that the result be displayed in the DatagridView even the other fields are empty (the client should tape one or more parameters to get the result that's why I put OR =>doesn't work,it works with AND :/

Comment: with "AND" I should fill all the parameters that's not what I want :(

Comment: Dear, "AND" and "OR is used to filter the data. Better to check select * with each condition, which give result or not? then merge one by one with or clause. so you know what happened. Finally you got everything. This whole thing done in sqlserver side and then change (if needed ) in c#.